# How do I create a ribbon?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, ribbon

I wanted to create a Ribbon in my current project, but since I've never used ribbons before I dont even know how start...

The ribbon should look like this:

[image: ExampleRibbon]

On the last longer part I want to add an image inside. Other parts (first light-red and second dark-red parts have to be empty).
I saw many examples online, but nothing that looked like this. Hope someone can help me here...

HTML:

```
<div class=header-ribbon>
   ...
   ...
   <img...>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
?...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clip-path with gradient can do it.

I used CSS variable so you can easily control the shape:

```css
.ribbon {
  --p1: 30%;
  --p2: 60%;
  --d: 20%;

  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red var(--p1), darkred 0 var(--p2), red 0);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, var(--p1) 0,var(--p2) var(--d), 100% var(--d), 100% calc(100% - var(--d)), var(--p2) calc(100% - var(--d)), var(--p1) 100%, 0 100%)
}
```

```html
<div class="ribbon"></div>
```

Comment: Could you use an background image in the last part?

Comment: @0stone0 yes: https://jsfiddle.net/e3Lv2to5/

Answer (score 2):

If you want 3 separate DOM elements, you can get the desired output using
[`transform()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) with [`perspective()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/perspective) and [`rotateY()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotateY):

```
transform-origin: left center;
transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(30deg);
```

I've added a [placeholder image](https://placehold.co/200x34/eb6a6a/black?text=IMG%20BAR%27) to the last part as requested in you question.

---

```css
html, body { height: 100vh; width: 100vw; }

.rib {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    background: red;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 25px
}

.rir {
    height: 34px;
    width: 200px;
    background: url('https://placehold.co/200x34/eb6a6a/black?text=IMG%20BAR');
    margin-left: 282px;
    margin-top: -42px;
}

.bak {
    margin-left: 225px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #913535;
    perspective: 800px;
    transform-origin: left center;
    transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(30deg);
}

.text-center {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="rib text-center">FOO</div>
   <div class="bak"></div>
   <div class="rir text-center"></div>
</div
```